# JQuery calculate values for dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to generate a price based on radio button selections, on input fields that are added (sort of like a list). Unfortunately since each set of radio buttons added has a unique name (so that they can be parsed separately later) the function that calculates the price is pulling the radio buttons value by it's name. This is clearly problematic since there are multiple instances of the same scenario.

Anyone?
http://jsfiddle.net/pxrpF/1/

I'm also looking to generate a Grand Total that will add up each set, so if anyone can help me figure these two bits out that would be wonderful!

Comment: Have you thought about using arrays in your field names? E.g. <input type="radio" name="cost[0]" value="1000" /> and then looping through the cost array in the post or serialized data?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do this, but sounds like a possibility :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should handle the problem with grabbing the right radio buttons:

```
var containerCount = $(this).parents('.container').prevAll('.container').size();

var $r = $('.container:eq('+containerCount+')').find(cardType);
var $d = $('.container:eq('+containerCount+')').find(cardQ);
```

**EDIT (to incorporate conversation below)**

In addition, the selector strings `cardType` and `cardQ` should be as follows:

```
var cardType = ":radio[name*='type']:checked"
var cardQ = ":radio[name*='quantity']:checked"
```

The `*=` ensures that the attribute starts with type or quantity respectively.

Comment: Not sure if I'm implementing this wrong but it still isn't calculating the price for subsequent items: http://jsfiddle.net/pxrpF/6/

Also, the if clause is so that it doesn't output NaN when you only select one of the radio buttons, I only want it to execute the calculation once both selections have been made so that it generates the correct total.

Comment: My mistake.  The solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/VivekVish/pxrpF/8/ The problem was that the selector was looking for type1 instead of just looking for something that started with type.

Comment: Thanks so much Vivek! I really appreciate it. Now I just need to calculate the grand total.